# 4G signal with mobile turned off

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mobile-network, 4g

Recently I have noticed that my cellular company (TIM, I'm in Brazil) has been charging me for network connections daily. I rarely use cellular network since at home and in my job has wifi and I don't mind being 30 minutes without internet.
I called them and they said it's due the device having its preffered network at 4G, not 3G. When I changed the preffered network to 3g, it stopped charging me. They won't retrieve my money because they received a signal so for them there was an internet connection (even though the data received is like 1kb). It's horrible to keep changing it to 3g/4g every time I need to turn it off or on.

But anyway, my device is a Motorola X Play running Android 6.0.1. 
The question is: does Android send 4g signal even with mobile data turned off? If so, is there a way to make it stop?

Edit: Following some comments, I lsoe signal a lot due the subway and closed places. That could explain it?

Comment: To me it sounds like a-hole company. It doesn't make sense why would 4g consume data when mobile data is off on that sense 3g should consume too. Or at least no one charges. Let's say someone have prepaid sim card and uses 4g and then run out of credit, in that moment he won't be able to connect to 4g, right? I guess it's just a way to charge you for using 4g for that company.

Comment: No, but it is entirely possible that every time you toggle it on and off, it is searching for a signal and connects momentarily with LTE (4G) then drops back to 3G. I don't have any proof or documentation regarding this, but it seems plausible and explains the issue. Is there a way to stop it, probably not.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје yes, I believe it's a way for them to get your money by making you tired of complaining.

Comment: @acejavelin yes, I thought about that but if I never turn it on for two days and neither turn off the phone or anything, would that still happen?

Comment: @Geo possibly... If you lost signal and it had to re-aquire it, or maybe (more remotely) when it switches towers. There is a possibility your carrier is requesting your device to change bands too.

Comment: Oh, I lose signal a lot due subway and closed places. That could explain this @acejavelin